# Not able to get Task record during an EmailMessage deletion trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, tasks, emailmessage, isdeleted

During an EmailMessage related to a Lead deletion, I need to be able to get the associated Lead on the Task (ActivityId field on EmailMessage object) and add it to the correct list.
In the following code, during the second debug,"activityIds" has the id of a task:

```
System.debug('Tasks: ' + activityIds);
```

But then, the query on t2 gets no records:

```
List<Task> t2 = [SELECT Id, WhoId, WhatId, TaskSubtype FROM Task WHERE Id IN :activityIds AND TaskSubtype = 'Email'];
```

Full code here:

```
if(trigger.old!=null){
        System.debug('EmailMessage Trigger old');
        for(EmailMessage em : Trigger.old) {
            activityIds.add(em.ActivityId);    
        }
        System.debug('Tasks: ' + activityIds);

        List<Task> t2 = [SELECT Id, WhoId, WhatId, TaskSubtype FROM Task WHERE Id IN :activityIds AND TaskSubtype = 'Email'];
        System.debug('Tasks: ' + t2);


        for(Task ta : t2){
            if(ta.WhoId != null){
                System.debug('EmailMessage Trigger old - Has WhoId');
                if(string.valueof(ta.WhoId).startsWith(leadPrefix)){
                    System.debug('EmailMessage Trigger old - Has WhoId - Is Lead');
                    if(ta.TaskSubtype == 'Email'){
                        System.debug('EmailMessage Trigger old - Has WhoId - Is Lead - Is Email');
                        if(!leadIdsEmails.contains(ta.WhoId)){
                            leadIdsEmails.add(ta.WhoId);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions.
Thank you in advance.